# Payment processor for WHMCS that supports recurring payments?

Tags: payment-gateway, whm, recurring-billing

Anybody use WHMCS (WHM Complete Solution) that found any of the supported modules that allow recurring billing. I'm currently looking at 2checkout, but can't get a clear answer anywhere.

Comment: This was a helpful question.

Answer (score 4):

We use both paypal and 2checkout, both work very well but the cheapest to run would be "gocardless" for whmcs, free setup and module support, but is UK direct debit only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Paypal Subscriptions, works pretty well with WHMCS- https://www.paypal.com/uk/mrb/pal=VMMKH6NB98JS4